# нумерация списков средством css

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени!
подскажите как сделать такую нумерацию на чистом css
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.goals {
  counter-reset: num;
  list-style: none;
  font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";
  padding: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.goals ol {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  /*background: #23b7a4;*/
}

.goals ol li {
  content: counter(item) ' ';
  /* Добавляем к числам скобку */
  counter-increment: item;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="goals">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h3>Dedication to the customers</h3>
      <div>Integer vel lacus non dui ullamcorper venenatis. Aliquam vitae tristique nisi, vitae ullamcorper risus.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>working closely with our clients</h3>
      <div>Sed blandit nisi urna, sed pellentesque enim consectetur vitae. Suspendisse ut vehicula nibh.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>increase happiness</h3>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend laoreet euismod.</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

не могу понять как убрать точки у нумерации и украсить именно нумерацию, пробовал создать нумерацию через content:counter(item); counter-increment:item, но не могу понять как сделать 01, 02 и тд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.goals {
  font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 12px;
}
ol { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li { 
  display: block;
}

li + li {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

li > * {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

li:before { 
  float: left;
  display: block;
  content: counter(item, decimal-leading-zero) " "; 
  counter-increment: item;
  background-color: #23b7a4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="goals">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h3>Dedication to the customers</h3>
      <div>Integer vel lacus non dui ullamcorper venenatis. Aliquam vitae tristique nisi, vitae ullamcorper risus. Integer vel lacus non dui ullamcorper venenatis. Aliquam vitae tristique nisi, vitae ullamcorper risus.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>working closely with our clients</h3>
      <div>Sed blandit nisi urna, sed pellentesque enim consectetur vitae. Suspendisse ut vehicula nibh.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>increase happiness</h3>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend laoreet euismod.</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: отлично, это уже приблизительно то что надо, а не подскажете еще как стили к этим 01 и 02 прицепить?

Comment: а почему появился отступ списка от левого края? и как задать 0? margin-left: 0; ничего не меняет

Comment: @agafron, так как `before` находится непосредственно в `li`. Единое решение я вижу добавить что-то такое: `li > * { margin-left: 60px; }` **P.S:** обновил пост

Comment: @agafron, не правильно вас понял сначала :) там `-webkit-padding-start` устанавливается браузером к `ol`.

Comment: добавил к ol {margin-left: -40px;} и все выровнялось, так правильно? или есть более элегантный способ?

Comment: @agafron, просто сделать reset: `padding: 0px;`. И судя по вашему скриншоту, контент в `li` должен не переноситься (поменял в примере - см. `li > *` )

Comment: понял, спасибо, еще один вопрос, почему ol { padding 0} не работает для отступа сверху, там тоже нужен 0, я вышел из положения присвоив li {margin-top: -18px; }, хотя, интуитивно догадываюсь, что это не православно)

Comment: @agafron, обновил ответ.

Comment: все на самом деле так просто, спасибо! буду дальше заниматься, сорян за тупку)

Comment: @agafron, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример того что вы хотите. Это сделано с псевдоклассом `:before`.

Там нумерация происходит так. `content: '0' counter(item);`.

Стили немного не то что на вашей картинке. Но принцип уже понятен.

Стили можете оформить на ваш вкус.

```css
.goals {
  counter-reset: num;
  list-style: none;
  font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";
  padding: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.goals ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.goals ol li {
  /* Добавляем к числам скобку */
  counter-increment: item;
}
.goals ol li:before {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   content: counter(item, decimal-leading-zero);
   background: #2CB3A4;
   border-radius: 2px;
   color: white;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   font-size: 32px;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;
 }


h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="goals">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h3>Dedication to the customers</h3>
      <div>Integer vel lacus non dui ullamcorper venenatis. Aliquam vitae tristique nisi, vitae ullamcorper risus.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>working closely with our clients</h3>
      <div>Sed blandit nisi urna, sed pellentesque enim consectetur vitae. Suspendisse ut vehicula nibh.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>increase happiness</h3>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend laoreet euismod.</div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нумерацию именно списка так не получится стилизовать.
Можно просто убрать список и сделать цифры обычными блоками и стилизовать как душе угодно)

```css
.number{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #23b7a4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="number">01</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3 class="content__title">Dedication to the customers</h3>
      <p class="content__text">Integer vel lacus non dui ullamcorper venenatis. Aliquam vitae tristique nisi, vitae ullamcorper risus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="number">02</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3 class="content__title">working closely with our clients</h3>
      <p class="content__text">Sed blandit nisi urna, sed pellentesque enim consectetur vitae. Suspendisse ut vehicula nibh.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="number">03</div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3 class="content__title">increase happiness</h3>
      <p class="content__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend laoreet euismod.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно сделать. Посмотрите ответ.

Comment: @RazGalstyan да, через :before тоже была такая мысль, но по сути создается тот же блок, только псевдоэлементом, конечно плюс, что не нужно лишних блоков)